# Filter SharePoint Business Data List By Audience

Tags: sharepoint-2007, bdc

I'm using a Business Data List that displays a list of programs.  I want to be able to filter the list based on the audience / user viewing the page.  Also, does anyone know if it's possible to retrieve the audience variable from within the XSL stylesheet?  If so, I can probably apply the filter through that instead of the web part.

Answer (score 0):

Create as many web parts as audience groups you have to target. Then set the `Target Audience` field in the Advance WebPart properties for each one of them to the appropriate group.